# Can you use one card on multiple obstacles?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

I'm just started playing shadowrun crossfire prime runner, and I had a question about if you can play one black market card on two or more obstacles. Like if a black market card has a face damage and mana damage it it's damage category in the top left. Can I use the face on one obstacle, and the mana on another obstacle? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Black Market cards work in much the same way as the basic cards, unless they have an ability which lets them damage multiple obstacles, they will deal all of their damage to a single obstacle.